# Android Support Library 21 toolbar losing theme

Tags: android, android-toolbar

My question is in continuation to this question [Toolbar NavigationIcon loose theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808917/toolbar-navigationicon-loose-theme). This is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=78289) in support library 21.

In my case i have two activities with two different theme toolbars. When I navigate back from Activity2 to Activity1, Activity1 toolbar buttons (back and overflow) take Activity2's theme.

I am trying to do a workaround for this problem and this what I have tried so far.

`onResume()` of my Activity1

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    if(mToolbar != null) {
        // set navigation icon
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    }
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}
```

`onPrepareOptionsMenu` of Activity1

```
    @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // set overflow icon
    for(int i = 0; i < mToolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if(mToolbar.getChildAt(i) instanceof ActionMenuView) {
            ActionMenuView v = (ActionMenuView)mToolbar.getChildAt(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < v.getChildCount(); j++) {
                if(v.getChildAt(j) instanceof TintImageView) {
                    TintImageView v1 = (TintImageView)v.getChildAt(j);
                    v1.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

with this workaround my back button is working fine but overflow icon comes in Activity2's theme untill I press it once. Once pressed it changes its theme. Also I am using `Searchview` in Activity1 and when its activated then only overflow icon appears.

Let me know if more information is required.